# bootstrap-How to make a form's input full-width in form-horizontal?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

this is my first question so please bear with me:
I'm trying to create a form-horizontal but the input doesn't span full width as I want even when specify col-md-8 and col-md-12 in the form-group parent div:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By_sHYp4kCXETzh3aWRZaHc2a1k/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the html code I used https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By_sHYp4kCXEdld0bDY4Qk9TNEk/edit?usp=sharing

What do I miss :(?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your site.css on line no. 13 you have max-width set to 280px for input.Remove that and you will get the output you want.

Comment: Thanks Aqib1604. That fixed the problem. Quick question: how did you find that out? Which tool can I use to find out which css settings are applied to a tag?

Comment: I am using firebug evtention in firefox.